# Why HTML <input type="color"> does not work at first?

Tags: html, input, colors

I am creating a text editor with HTML and I want to change font color.

```
<input id="fore-color" type="color" value="#ffffff" onchange="changeWithArgs('foreColor', this.value)">
```

When I open it on Chrome, at first it can't implement a color till I choose one of basic colors. After that it starts to work normally,but how can I choose my prefered color at once?

Issue is provided in [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kV2B.png). Also it can't change color | solid property.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select the color from basic color or custom colors. But by default whatever color you mentioned in the value attr will be the default one selected once the page is loaded.

Comment: The problem is that it does not let me add a custom color. At first time it only lets me choose from basic colors. In the above photo I've chosen a pinkish color, but it still showsblack in color | solid property

Comment: You are missing to change shade at the right end of the color box, change it to different cllor and that will let your change ur custom color

Answer (score 1):

actually when you are selecting color then the right most bar is set at black(as black triangle is set to that).... You have to change the placement of black colored triangle besides the right most bar to change the color

Answer (score -3):

You have to specify the type of input in HTML; for example, `type="text"` `type="checkbox"` etc. There is no value`"color"` for the `type` attribute of an input.

Comment: There is type="color" attribute for input. Did I understand you wrong?

Comment: Yes there not exsiste input type color but type text, checkbox, submit, etc

Comment: There is an input type color: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp